# Task Sequence boots to logon screen instead of task sequence mode

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I'm running a task sequence, and so that users don't accidentally interfere, I have the task sequence reboot to currently installed operating system, which as I understand, is supposed to boot to a sort of single user mode and all that shows is task sequence progress.  However, this does not happen, it boots up like normal and comes to the logon screen and the task sequence runs in background.  How can I adjust this behavior to the desired result?
Edit: to clarify, this is the sort of screen I want my users to see rather than the Ctrl+Alt+Del sign-in screen
[image]

Comment: Could you add more detail about what you are trying to accomplish? See the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have created a task sequence to install the Windows 8.1 Enterprise upgrade.  I want it to reboot into the task sequence mode so that it basically prevents the user from doing anything while the task sequence is in progress.  I've seen this behavior in other task sequences, primary OSD (when it boots into the OS, not the winpe mode) and I want to take advantage of it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how this is done in those other task sequences, and its an effort I don't wish to duplicate.  Reading the scripts these others specify, it runs off an auto logon and then other scripts to set the environment.  Far too much effort for this simple project.  Thank you to everyone who responded on this though.